# angularJS : watch if value change and if value not change

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have this watch function to detect if one of the items changed and return true if changed; return false if not changed.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
                return angular.toJson([ithem1 , ithem2]);
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    $scope.Changed= true;
            });
```

With this I can detect changes, but if nothing changed, how can I get $scope.Changed set to false?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
            return angular.toJson([ithem1 , ithem2]);
        }, function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                scope.Changed = newValue !== oldValue;
        });
```

So if newValue is different from the oldValue then changed is true, otherwise it is false.

Comment: if you dont change value it dont see ' $scope.Changed = newValue !== oldValue; ' and function stop in return

Comment: I edited my answer to include the scope variable in the watch function, if you mean that you cannot see the scope inside of the changing function. Does this work for you?

Comment: I put a break-point in the condition if i dont change one of ithem and i change something else , he ignore my break point and dont go in

Comment: So do you mean that your $scope.changed should be by default false, and change to true only when you change one of your items? If yes, then I think you only need to add a $scope.Changed = false; line before setting the watch.